# How to get equation of plane given two (or three) lines - these lines are on separate Z planes that do not intersect..Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have three lines and they are on three planes (z = z1, z = z2, z = z3). They are of the form y=mx+b. These lines do not intersect...but how can I get the equation of the plane that contains all three?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define the equation for the three lines on parallel planes
m1 = 0.011245
b1 = 13.52699
z1 = 416
m2 = 0.01133
b2 = 15.00847
z2 = 469
m3 = 0.013082
b3 = 19.767
z3 = 633



fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111, projection = '3d')
ax1.invert_zaxis()

xx = np.linspace(0, 800, 800)
yy = np.linspace(0, 800, 800)

xx, yy = np.meshgrid(xx, yy)
zz = (A * xx + B * yy + D)/(-C)

xa = np.linspace(0, 800, 800)
ya = m1 * xa + b1
za = 416

xb = np.linspace(0, 800, 800)
yb = m2 * xb + b2
zb = 469

xc = np.linspace(0, 800, 800)
yc = m2 * xc + b3
zc = 633

##ax1.plot_surface(xx, yy, zz, alpha = 0.5)
ax1.plot(xa, ya, za)
ax1.plot(xb, yb, zb)
ax1.plot(xc, yc, zc)
ax1.set_xlabel('X')
ax1.set_ylabel('Y')
ax1.set_zlabel('Z')
plt.show()
```

[image]

This code should at least define the plane, but when you plot it - it does not contain all the lines. I don't think this is correct

```
# Define the line
P1 = np.array([xx1, yy1, z1])
P2 = np.array([xx2, yy2, z1])
d = P2 - P1

# Define the point
Q = np.array([xx3, yy3, z2])

# Find the normal vector
N = np.cross(d, Q - P1)

# Find d
d = np.dot(N, Q)

# Print the equation of the plane
print(f"{N[0]}x + {N[1]}y + {N[2]}z = {d}")
```

Comment: Two lines define a plane IFF they are intersecting, and a third line is in this plane IFF it intersects the other two lines. Think about it.